# Grub problem - elementary OS installed alongside Windows 8.1 - unable to boot linux

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, dual-boot

this is a log from boot-repair:
http://paste2.org/GcL2vLU6

I've installed elementary OS on /sdb. /sda is a SSD with Win 8.1 on it. Didn't have spare space on /sda so I've put boot info on /sdb. During install there was a fatal error, but I've chosen /sdb as a boot and installation ended successfully. After restart Win 8.1 booted, no grub, no questions asked.

I've checked BIOS, in "Boot" menu there was no UEFI options to enable/disable.

I have Asus K551 (a.k.a. S551) laptop. Help!

Almost forgot - I've tried to repair boot with boot-repair (obviously) and it replied that I need to repair this in UEFI mode, not Legacy mode - what's Legacy Mode? Right now I'm on USB stick, with elementary OS Live. I can boot only to Windows, can I repair grub from there?
Also I've noticed that boot-repair signals there's no boot loader on /sda nor /sdb - what's up with that? How to fix this?

edit2: I've managed to done something with boot-repair, these are the results:
http://paste2.org/M6OZmXEG

I'm going to reboot now, see you in a bit.

Comment: I've checked in Win8.1 in what mode it is installed - using msinfo32 - it's UEFI. Boot option from BIOS contains only "Launch PXE OpROM" - something like that, and it is disabled. When I've changed to "enabled" Win8.1 looped into "preparing to fix windows now"-mode, and still I can't see GRUB. When starting from USB stick (elementary OS or Mint) and using boot-repair it's always results with "this app is launched in legacy mode, not efi mode". I can't figure out this one...

Comment: I've somehow managed to get it done myself. I've GRUB working, can choose between Win 8.1, eOS and some other stuff.